# Ajax callback from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass two number and check if their product is true or false. I can see call made successfully in network tab and when i click that link, output is correct to. But i m stuck at retrieving that result. It doesn't show anything in data1.

```
function call(){
    console.log(fun);
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/mt2/checkanswer.php",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  type: "POST",
           //window.alert("what");
  data: {
    num1:2,
      num2:2,
      answer:5

  },
  success: function( data1 ) {
     console.log(data1);
    $( "#timeDiv" ).html( "<strong>" + data1 + "</strong><br>");
  }

<?php

  // get two numbers and the answer (their product) and return true or false if the answer is correct or not. 
  // using this as an api call, return json data
  // calling <your host>/checkanswer.php?num1=4&num2=5&answer=20 will return true
  // calling <your host>/checkanswer.php?num1=4&num2=5&answer=21 will return false

  if(isset($_GET['num1']) && isset($_GET['num2']) && isset($_GET['answer']) && is_numeric($_GET['num1']) && is_numeric($_GET['num2']) && is_numeric($_GET['answer'])) {

    $product = $_GET["num1"] * $_GET["num2"];

    if ($product === intval($_GET['answer'])) {
      $result = true;
    } else {
      $result = false;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);

  } 
?>
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ocF344ZxG3HXJR0WQha1kOoVM9bCepnI "console"

Comment: Are you outputting anything is checkanswer.php? What does console.log(data1); show? Maybe include the code in the ajax'd file too.

Comment: if data1 is empty then checkanswer.php doesnt output anything

Comment: data1 doesn't show anything in console, but if try calling directly with php fit showsoutput. Even network tab shows call being made.

Comment: so lets get things straight..
first add an else in your php file and echo something out also on your javascript ajax, can you handle the error callback and  log it

Comment: Try $result = array('success'=>true); // or false and see if the data1 shows anything. Or try return a '0' or '1' string instead of true/false and don't json encode it and see what happens.

Comment: Yes add an else to if(isset($_GET['num1']) &&....  to see if the code is even being ran or not as @Paul mentioned. I have a feeling something is not passing your checks inside the if and it's just never entering that code to output anything.

Comment: Your ajax is submitting as a `POST` request and your PHP is looking for a `GET` request- `$_GET[..]` should be `$_POST[..]`.

Comment: Aside: you can replace `isset($a) && isset($b) && isset($c)` with `isset($a, $b, $c)`.

Comment: @WildBeard you indeed paid attention to details... so this explains why trying it from the browser works and outputs because the browser sends a GET request.

Comment: You can not do jsonp with post

Comment: @epascarello - nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your Javascript is submitting the data via JS as a post request and your PHP is looking for a get request.

```
if(isset($_GET['num1']) && isset($_GET['num2']) && isset($_GET['answer']) && is_numeric($_GET['num1']) && is_numeric($_GET['num2']) && is_numeric($_GET['answer'])) {
 ..
}
```

So either change `method: 'POST'` to `method: 'GET'` or change `$_GET[..]` to `$_POST[..]`.

Also that's one wild if statement. You could break it up so it's not so long and isn't as hard to read. This also allows you to add some additional information based on where your code 'fails.'

```
if ( isset($_GET['num1'], $_GET['num2'], $_GET['answer']) ) {

  if ( !is_numeric([$_GET['num1'], $_GET['num2'], $_GET['answer']]) ) {
    // Our numbers aren't numeric!
    $message = 'Not all variables are numeric';
    $result = false;
  } else {
    $message = 'We did it!';
    $result = $_GET['num1'] + $_GET['num2'] == $_GET['answer'];
  }

} else {
  // We didn't have all of our request params passed!
  $message = 'We didn\'t have all our variables';
  $result = false;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode([ 'message' => $message, 'result' => $result]);
```

#### Edit

Based on epascarello's comment remove `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Comment: Its not even getting call, when i remove datattype: 'jsonp'

Comment: @ManjinderGrewal that is left for you to debug. The question is have you modified your  ajax code to send a GET? or rather modify your PHP code to receive a POST instead of GET?

Comment: I changed call method to GET